# Ajax to controller function(codeigniter) not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Loading the builder controller

```
<a class = "button tiny" href = "<?php echo site_url('builder/app/'.$experiment->eid); ?>"> Edit </a>
```

CodeIgniter Controller

```
class Builder extends MY_Controller{      
    public function index(){
        $data['title'] = 'Experiment';
        $data['main_content'] = 'experiment/add_experiment_form';
        $this->load->view('_main_layout', $data);   
    }

    public function app($eid = 0){
        $data['title'] = 'Experiment';
        $data['eid'] = $eid;
        $data['main_content'] = 'experiment/add_experiment_form';
        $this->load->view('_main_layout', $data);
    }

    public function save() {
        $message = $this->input->post('msg');
        echo $message;
    }
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$("#getObjectValues").click(function () {
            var msg = '[';
            for(i=1; i<$.count; i++){
                if (i!=1) {msg+=","}
                var offset = $('#obj'+i).offset();
                var xPos = offset.left;
                var yPos = offset.top;
                msg += "("+xPos+","+yPos+")";
            }
            msg += ']';

            $.ajax({
                url:"builder/save",
                type:"POST",
                data:{'msg':msg},
                success: function(data) {
                    alert('success '+data);
                    window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url($this->session->userdata('active_role').'/experiments'); ?>";
                }

            });
        });
```

Clicking the edit button from another html file triggers the app function from the builder controller. It then loads the page `add_experiment_form` with the supplied javascript is a separate html file. When the `getObjectValues button` is clicked, the variable msg to collect some information. Then using ajax, I pass msg to the controller `function save()`. The problem arises when I `alert` the `variable s` on the success part. It prompts the raw HTML of the `add_experiment_form` rather than the `$message` from the `save() function`.

The thing is when the I change the `button's href` to just `'builder'`, the whole system is working properly, meaning the `success function alerts` the right message, not the whole html code.

Comment: check url is OK or not I mean open site_ur+/builder/save url in browser and chek what happen then call that url through ajax

Answer (score 0):

use `echo json_encode($message);` then response on success

```
 var = $.parseJSON($data);
 alert (json)
```

Comment: I've edited my code from `echo $message;` to `echo json_encode($message);` and on my js, `success: function(data) { var json= $.parseJSON(data); alert(json);}`. The console prints this error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Comment: please show your data what is encoded alert (data) first then into json